# Return HTTP 200 on hardcoded endpoint in Java App

Tags: java, localhost, health-monitoring

I have a standard Java app (not Spring Boot) and want it to return OK when I ping `localhost:8080/health` I am a complete beginner to anything web dev. Most of the resources online are for Spring Boot apps (which this isn't). Other StackOverflow posts say to use `ServerSocket`, but is there a higher level way to do this?

Would really appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a class which implements the Sprint Boot's HealthIndicator and then create the method health() :

```
@Component
public class HealthIndicatorImpl implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {    
        return Health.up().build();
    }
}
```

This instruction return "OK" when you called the localhost:8080/health :

```
return Health.up().build()
```

In addition, if you want to show a KO, you can write :

```
return Health.down().withDetail(/* code */, /* message */).build();
```

Comment: It was an old manner to proceed (with Spring Boot 1.5.3) but I think it can be ok with future releases.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without Spring Boot? Or is it the norm to use Spring Boot?

Comment: Is there a way to do what ? A Web application ?
I'm very sorry to say this but it totally depends on what you want to do. Spring Boot is one framework to make web applications but you have plenty of languages and frameworks and libraries...

Comment: That makes sense, I was confused by the terminologies. Thanks!